# Getting access denied on the destination drive partition after using xcopy

Tags: windows, xcopy

I wanted to copy the all the files in a folder including its sub-folders from one hard drive to another

I tried this xcopy command

```
C:\Documents and Settings\rakesh>xcopy "D:\Ganesh Drive\Trimax soft important" "
H:\" /E /k /x
```

but after executing this command I am getting access denied on the destination drive partition.
Please let me why and how rectify this issue.

Comment: Your question shows the second parameter to `xcopy` as `"` `(space)` `H` `:` `\ ` `"`.  If that’s what you’re doing, try eliminating the space between the quote and the `H`.         ...         And, if you don't have any spaces in that directory pathname, you don't need the quotes.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is long time ago, but since I had the same problem from the same kind of command (xcopy targeting a volume root with /x), I thought about sharing the solution.

This appears to be a bug in xcopy (Windows XP SP3 version 5.1.2600.5512 at least), where the root directory entry ”.” of the target directory gets its ACL erased.

Fixed it with ”CACLS [drive letter:] /g Everyone:F”.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried command prompt elevation, all possible switches with the xcopy command and had zero luck in copying the encrypted files (these files are highlighted in green )

After some googling, i was able to come up with a solution...the answer is **robocopy** and it works like a charm . This took a day's R&D

The switch that does this job is /EFSRAW . It copies all encrypted files in EFS RAW mode.

Your command would be something like

```
robocopy source destination /COPY:DATS /MIR /EFSRAW /R:2 /W:0 /E /ETA
```

Note - Robocopy is not an inbuilt feature in 2003 servers. It has to be installed separately. Also certain ESI files and certificates have to be  imported to get the /EFSRAW switch to work in 2003 servers. This  is not required on 2008, Vista and w7 servers.